# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onload

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to pull info from a JSON file into JavaScript and then to an HTML page but it keeps erroring when I get to a for loop that takes info from said file.

```
 function digiLevel() {
             document.getElementById("digivice").innerHTML = "Loading...";

                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            var textBox = document.getElementById("digivice");

                              var output1 = "";
                              var output2 ="";
                              var output3 = "";        
                              var digimon = xmlhttp.responseText;

                            console.dir(digimon);
                            digimon = JSON.parse(digimon);
                            console.dir(digimon);

                            output1 = "<ul>";
                            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                                output2 += "<li>" + digimon[i].name + " is a(n) " + digimon[i].level + "</li><br>";
                            }
                            output3 = "</ul>";

                            textBox.innerHTML = output1 + output2 + output3;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://ec2-54-158-64-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Challenge9/webService.php?content=data&format=json", true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
```

And it returns the Uncaught TypeError on the line

```
 output2 += "<li>" + digimon[i].name + " is a(n) " + digimon[i].level + "</li><br>";
```

I don't see how 'name' is undefined?? Maybe I'm just blind; it's 1AM here.

EDIT:

Thanks for the guiding comments; I was able to find my error:

digimon by itself didn't have a name tag of its own even with an index variable, and so I accessed the name tag by

```
    digimon.digivice.digimon[i].name
```

after returning digimon to the console to analyze its contents. I'm still new to working with JSON/XML so if there is a faster/more efficient/effective way to achieve the same result, do please let me know!

Comment: Well it means `digimon[i]` is undefined, ie doesn't exist. Check `digimon` actual contains what you think it does. Just looking at the json at the api endpoint in your example you aren't accessing the data correctly, which you should see in the consoled object view

Comment: @Zeo run this `for loop` inside this check `if(digimon) { // for loop here}`.  Looks like you are not getting data in your `digimon` var

Comment: Make your for-loop as `for (i = 0; i < digimon.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
digimon = JSON.parse(digimon);
```

to:

```
digimon = JSON.parse(digimon).digivice.digimon
```

according to your code :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://ec2-54-158-64-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Challenge9/webService.php?content=data&format=json", true);
```

and better change this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; i < digimon.length; i++) {
```

Comment: How/from-where did you got the info related to `digimon = JSON.parse(digimon).digivice.digimon` ? OP hasn't shared anything related to this.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://ec2-54-158-64-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Challenge9/webService.php?content=data&format=json", true);`

Answer (score 2):

> And it returns the Uncaught TypeError on the line
>
> ```
>  output2 += "<li>" + digimon[i].name + " is a(n) " + digimon[i].level + "</li><br>";
> ```

Not sure why you have hard-coded your for-loop as

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //where is 6 coming from
```

Looks like somewhere during the iteration, `digimon[i]` doesn't exists (is `undefined`), so make your for-loop condition as

```
for (i = 0; i < digimon.length; i++) { //where is 6 coming from
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let fetchbtn = document.getElementById('fetchbtn');
let popbtn = document.getElementById('populate');
fetchbtn.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler)
popbtn.addEventListener('click', pophandler)

function buttonClickHandler() {
  console.log('You Have Clicked The Fetch Button')
  //Create XHR Object
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //Open The Object
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create', true);
  xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
  //What To Do On Progress
  xhr.onprogress = function() {
    console.log('On Progress')
  }
  // xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
  //     console.log('ready state', xhr.readyState)
  // }
  //Response Is Ready
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText)
      console.log('We are done')

    } else {
      console.error('Some Error Occoured')
    }
  }
  //Send Data
  params = `{"name":"Krishna","salary":"210000","age":"1234568945465"}`;
  xhr.send(params)

}

function pophandler() {
  console.log('You Have Just Clicked The Populate Handler')
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.json', true)
  xhr.getResponseHeader = ('Content-type', 'application/j-son')
  xhr.onprogress = function() {
    console.log('Loading Pop')
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function statechange() {
    console.log('Current Loading State Is ', xhr.readyState)
  }
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
      console.log(obj)
      let list = document.getElementById('list');
      str = "";
      for (i in obj) {
        str += `<li>${obj[i].name}</li>`;
      }
      list.innerHTML = str;
      console.log('We Are Done')
    } else if (this.status === 429) {
      console.error('To Many Requests')
    } else {
      console.error('Some Error Occoured')
    }

  }

  xhr.send()
}
// http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <title>Hello, AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-4">
    <h1>AJAX Tutorial</h1>
    <button type="button" id="fetchbtn" title='Fetch Data' class="btn btn-primary">Write Data</button>
    <button type="button" id="populate" title='Populate Data' class="btn btn-success">Fetch Data</button>

    <ul id="list">
      <h1></h1>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```